# Contents of textfile on URL to be displayed iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url

Trying to get the contents of a textfile on this url but it doesnt seem to work. Any Help?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLwithString:@"http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.9/keep-alive/keep-alive.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(content);
```

The actual textfile will only be 20 words but this is just an example.

Am i doing this wrong? or is it a lot harder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close...
Capital W in URLWithString 
NSError variabel as the error: parameter in NSString
Then it should work

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.9/keep-alive/keep-alive.txt"];
NSError* error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

You should also try using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which is a nice wrapper for the CFNetwork API